# Open a new function with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page in PHP and I would open a function with a click.

Function shows me a query result, but when I write this code it doesn't work

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Frequenza <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <?php
                $query_frequenza="SELECT DISTINCT FREQUENZA FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE  macchine_id='$macchine' and Email='$_SESSION[login_user]'";
                $result=mysqli_query($conne,$query_frequenza);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $frequenza=$row['FREQUENZA'];
                    echo"<li><a href='#?frequenza=$frequenza' onclick='showfiltro2()'>$frequenza</a></li>";
                }
                ?>
        </ul>
        </div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
            function showfiltro2() {
                document.getElementById("filtro2").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("filtro1").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
        <div id = "filtro2" style="display:none">
        <?php
            $filtro2=$_GET['frequenza'];
            $query="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE macchine_id='$macchine' and Email='$_SESSION[login_user]' and FREQUENZA='$filtro2' ";
            $result=mysqli_query($conne,$query);
            echo 'Found '. mysqli_num_rows($result) .'results';
            echo "<table><tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row['COMPONENTE'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['DETTAGLIO ATTIVITA'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['FREQUENZA'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['DATA-PREVISTA'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo"</tr></table>";
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: please clear your question... what you want?

Comment: You can't do it like this, you need to submit the page, anchors doesn't cause the page to reload so the php isn't cable of reading your $_GET variables.

Comment: And if i would open a function with  data coming from a menu?

Answer (score 3):

Your question stems from a misunderstanding of how PHP and HTML work, and how data flows between the two.

First off it's important to remember that PHP and HTML are two completely separate parts, which do not interact with each other outside of the "request->reply" chain.
This means that all of the PHP code gets executed on the server, before the client gets the output of this processing. The server (PHP) doesn't care about what kind of output it is, nor does it understand how to parse it; For all PHP knows, it's all simple text.
After the PHP code has been completely parsed, the client receives the resulting text. Then it notices that it can understand this text as HTML, and parses it as a web-page. At this point the PHP code doesn't exist in the code at all, and the web browser (client) doesn't know anything about it.

It is unfortunate that so many tutorials keep mixing PHP  and HTML code like you've done above, as this further confuses the two and makes it look like they're inter-communicative. What I recommend is to move all of your PHP code above any HTML-code, and do all of the processing before sending anything to the browser.
Not only will this make it a lot easier to actually keep track of, and understand, what's happening and why; But it will also allow you to add more functionality to your code, without trying to break the laws of physics. (For example: Deciding that you don't want to show a form to the user after all, half-way through the generation of said form.)

All this means that you don't "open a function" with a click. You send a request to the server with said click, and then the PHP code checks the incoming data for some predetermined condition (GET-parameter, etc), and then calls the function of said condition is fulfilled.
Something like this, in other words:

```
// First off we should use PDO, as mysql_*() is deprecated and removed in PHP7.
$db = new PDO ($dsn);

// Using prepared statements here, to prevent SQL injections.
$stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT DISTINCT FREQUENZA FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE  macchine_id=:machineID and Email=:email");
$data = array (':machineID' => $macchine, ':email' => $_SESSION['login_user']);
if (!$stmt->exec ($data)) {
    // Something went wrong, handle it.
}

// Initialize a variable to hold the generated menu, and a template to use when creating it.
$menuOut = $searchOut = '';
$menuTemplate = "<li><a href='#?frequenza=%s' onclick='showfiltro2()'>%s</a></li>";

// Using prepared statements we can iterate through all of the results with foreach().
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll () as $row) {
    // Using htmlspecialchars() and rawurlescape() to prevent against XSS, and other HTML-injection attacks/mistakes.
    // Notice where and in what order I've used the different functions, as one protects the URL as well.
    $menuOut .= sprintf ($menuTemplate, htmlspecialchars (rawurlencode ($row['FREQUENZA'])), htmlspecialchars ($row['FREQUENZA']));
}

// Since this is probably the "function" you want to execute with said click, this is where we check if it
// has been sent by the client.
if (!empty ($_GET['frequenza'])) {
    // Here you want to check to see if the parameter is actually something you'd expect, and not some random(?) garbage.
    $filtro2 = $_GET['frequenza'];

    // Again, prepared statements as your code was open to SQL injections!
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Dettagli_macchina WHERE macchine_id=:machineID and Email=:email and FREQUENZA=:frequency";;
    $stmt = $db->prepare ($query);
    $data = array (
            ':machineID' => $macchine,
            ':email' => $_SESSION['login_user'],
            ':frequency' => $filtro2);
    if (!$res = $stmt->exec ($data)) {
        // Somethign went wrong with the query, handle it.
    }

    // Initialize a variable to hold the output, and the template to use for generating it.
    $searchOut = '<table>';
    $searchTemplate = '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>';
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll () as $row) {
        // Again, protection against XSS and other HTML-breaking mistakes.
        $searchOut .= sprintf ($searchTemplate,
                htmlspecialchars ($row['COMPONENTE']),
                htmlspecialchars ($row['DETTAGLIO ATTIVITA']),
                htmlspecialchars ($row['FREQUENZA']),
                htmlspecialchars ($row['DATA-PREVISTA']));
    }

    $searchOut = "<p>Found {$count} results</p>{$searchOut}</table>";
}

?>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Frequenza <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<?php echo $menuOut; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function showfiltro2() {
                document.getElementById("filtro2").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("filtro1").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
<div id="filtro2" style="display: none">
    <?php echo $searchOut; ?>
</div>
```

I've added some comments to explain what and why I've done things, as well as changed over from the old(!), deprecated and obsolete `mysql_*()` functions to PDO.
You can read more about [how to use PDO in the PHP manual](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand very well what you are doing

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to study up on PHP. If there are specific parts you're wondering why I've done as I've done I can help shed light on those, but it is not possible for me to teach you everything you need to know in order to program proficiently in PHP. I've given you the tools to help you in this process, and I hope you'll take use of them until you do understand my example.